# Python: Skip error message and continue on in python loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

When data1 is not in file_i.hdf5:

```
KeyError: "unable to open object (Symbol table: Can't open object)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try:` and `except(KeyError):` to catch exceptions, as so.

```
import h5py

for i in range(0,100):
    try:
         with h5py.File('file_%s.hdf5' % i) as f:
             my_data = f['data1'][:]
             print i
    except(KeyError):
        # more code goes here...
```

Comment: I would recommend the try/except just around the `my_data = f[` line ... and on except `continue` ,else do your thing ...